# Best method to creating a Recommendation/Prediction Engine

Tags: php, prediction, recommendation-engine

I am here today to ask you how you would plan to develop a recommendation system. Please note that I am not asking for code, rather something along the lines of algorithm/maths.

The website I am working on offers a lot of items, each with hundreds of user ratings ranging from 0-5 in various categories, here's an example of an item table:

<kbd>ID</kbd><kbd>Name</kbd>      <kbd>Description</kbd><kbd>Average Rating</kbd><kbd>Cost</kbd><kbd>Usability</kbd><kbd>Functionality</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Drink</kbd>       <kbd>Blablabla</kbd>    <kbd>4.2</kbd>                    <kbd>2.2</kbd>  <kbd>2.3</kbd>         <kbd>4.0</kbd>              
<kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>Car</kbd>         <kbd>Blablabla</kbd>    <kbd>3.5</kbd>                    <kbd>3.3</kbd>  <kbd>3.0</kbd>         <kbd>4.4</kbd>              
<kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Bag</kbd>         <kbd>Blablabla</kbd>    <kbd>4.9</kbd>                    <kbd>5.0</kbd>  <kbd>4.2</kbd>         <kbd>0.2</kbd>              
<kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>Food</kbd>       <kbd>Blablabla</kbd>    <kbd>2.8</kbd>                    <kbd>2.1</kbd>  <kbd>4.8</kbd>         <kbd>1.2</kbd>

Now, whenever a user rates an item, it adds a row in a different table where all the ratings are saved. Once a day the server updates the values in the ITEMS (the above) table with the averages of all the approved ratings from the ratings table.

So the columns Cost, Usability and Functionality, and more, are the different categories that an item can have and a user can rate. The Average rating column is the median of all the categories.

That is the most important info regarding how everything is set up. Now, what I would like to do is let the user be able to search for items based on a search criteria using sliders. Something along the lines of a slider for each category and when the user submits the form.

Once submitted, it will go through each item and calculate a score based on what the user entered with the sliders. For example:

A user searches for 3 in Cost, 3 in Usability and 4 in Functionality and submits. The result should be the item(s) that best meet that criteria, which in this case would be (in order of best to worst match, ID's): 2, 1, 3, 4 approx.

How would I achieve doing this? Adding "weight" to each category. I've been doing a lot of research but I am not very experienced in advanced mathematics. It seems like calculating the Euclidean Distance and comparing them is a good idea, but I'd rather hear more approaches.

Comment: I'd say the best match would be derived via the sum of the square of the distances of each slider between the user's settings and the values for each row, and taking the lowest value (least distance). So if my sliders are `cost=2.3`, `usability=2.1`, `functionality=4` then it will be clear that the most appropriate thing for me is the Drink. You can weight each component separately too, if you think usability is more important than functionality, for example.

Comment: Aside: store your user's ratings separately - don't just store the average only. Think about what happens if you discover voting fraud: you disable the user account, and will need to recalculate all averages for all products he/she voted on.

Comment: There are a lot of recommendation questions here, incidentally -- please do read things in the sidebar over here `------>`.

Comment: @halfer Yeah, the single votes are stored. All votes need to be approved if the user doesn't already have an approved vote in the system. Can you please explain a little the formula you mention? I'm affraid I don't fully understand what you mean. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Also going into a little more advanced territory: would it be possible to implement a sort of "guided recommendation". Getting the average of all of a users ratings, and adding that to the equation to further improve the likelyhood of them getting a good match? Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to take into account the user's voting history, yes. It's not something I know a great deal about, so I can't really comment - I do know I've seen open source products to do all sorts of clever recommendation stuff here. I'd definitely suggest using a ready-made product here if you can, to save effort, and especially since you say it's not your area of expertise.

Comment: (Bear in mind that, since the question is interesting, I've not voted to place on hold as too discursive, but some people might have that opinion, and I don't want to go off on too much of a tangent for that reason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the outline of the simple algorithm I mentioned in the comments. Let's say a user's sliders are:

```
cost=2.3, usability=2.1, functionality=4
```

You can construct a SQL query that will try to minimise the "total distance" of these values from values in your table. Pseudo-SQL-code:

```
SELECT
   (cost - 2.3)^2 + (usability - 2.1)^2 + (functionality - 4)^2 AS score
FROM
   product_table
ORDER BY
   score
```

The purpose of the square (`^2`) is to prevent negative scores from cancelling each other out. I think you can just do `ABS()` here too (remove the minus) but taking a square seems to be a popular way to do this.

The result of this table is to list the products in order of recommendation, least distance first (i.e. most recommended, according to this simple algorithm).

If you wish, you can multiply each clause by a weight to make it more significant; a value of `1.0` will make no difference, a value less will reduce its effect, and a value greater will amplify its contribution. If you want to ignore one of these three measures entirely, just multiply its contribution by `0`, and that will ensure distance differences for that measure have no effect.

I can't remember if you can `ORDER BY` an aliased derived column, and it probably depends on what database you are using anyway. If it is not possible in your particular engine, make a view out of this, and then you can order by a "real" column.

---

Note that this requires user values to be injected into your SQL. If you can't use parameterisation here, be sure to cast/escape your data carefully.

Comment: Perfect answer. Couldn't have been more helpful! With the info you provided I know now where to continue and finish writing the script. Thanks halfer :)

Comment: Great. Let me know how you get on with it, it's an interesting problem.

Comment: Heya again, I have a quick question. This is the code I am running right now (I've simplified it for terms of legibility. It's also client sided, javascript/jQuery):

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=w5mgJqhg
Posted it on there due to formatting code.

So my question is now, that works great, but what if I want to let a user "ignore" a category. Let's say the user doesn't know how much the item should cost, he leave that slider at no value. How can I implement that into the function. I've been trying things out but without success. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh and my bad, to explain what is going on in the code. From the array of categories and slider values, it loops through each category, which in term loops through each list item adding the value of the ABS of the difference of the item's value and the slider value in the current category to the item's total. After that the list is re-sorted, from lowest total to highest. Being the lowest the "best match".

Comment: I've updated the answer with an extra note on ignoring a measure.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't think about multiplying it by 0 to null it out.
I'm now interested in finding out if I can create a kind of "this item is a 89% match" with this setup.
From this code, 0 is the lowest and best possible match. How can I equivlate 0 to be 100% best match and X to be 0% worst match.

I know this wasn't in scope of the original question but I'd appreciate the help. I've been trying various stuff but I'm having trouble getting 0 to be the best match. My initial idea was to calculate the percentage difference between the value and 0, then subtract that from 100%.

Comment: Well, I guess your maximum slider distance (assuming you are using all three) is three lots of 5. However in each case we are squaring, so the max distance is (5^2)*3. So your match percentage might be defined as the inverse of the distance we obtain from this algorithm, divided by 75. You can convert that into a percentage using `100 * ((75-distance)/75)` and then round. So you can see `distance=0` (ideal match) gives a high percentage, and `distance=75` (worst match) gives a low one.

Comment: You may wish to tweak that in the case of weighted or skipped clauses, however.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much for all your help. Seriously! Two massive thumbs up for all the great responses!

Comment: Also, remember not everyone on help sites is a dude. `;-)` And you are welcome, glad to be of help.

Comment: Haha whoops, my bad! Thanks again, I don't think I'm going to have to bother you again hehe